# Alternative to nested aligned environments

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

I am interested in producing an effect similar to that produced by the following nested aligned environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  A = ( 1 & + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 +10 + 11 + 12 \\
          &
            \begin{aligned}
              {} + 2 ( 1 & + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 \\
                      &
                        \begin{aligned}
                          {} + 3 ( 1 & + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 \\
                                  & + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4))
                        \end{aligned}
            \end{aligned} \\
          &
            \begin{aligned}
              {} + 2 ( 1 & + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8\\
                      & + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 3 + 5 + 6 ))
            \end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Is there a less syntax-intensive way to produce this type of effect?

Comment: @hooy I think it has been corrected.

Comment: @user161825: I corrected the spacing around some of your alignments; the operator is binary, so preceded it with `{}`. Also, I removed all the unnecessary information that doesn't pertain to your question.

Comment: @Werner Thank you! Can I ask you where I can read about whether to put the double braces or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With variable tab stops, nesting `aligned` is unavoidable. But you can have less `{}` and clearer input.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  A = ( 1 & + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 + 11 + 12 \\
          & + 2 ( \begin{aligned}[t]
                  1 & + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 \\
                    & + 3 ( \begin{aligned}[t]
                            1 & + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 \\
                              & + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4))
                            \end{aligned}
                  \end{aligned} \\
          & + 2 ( \begin{aligned}[t]
                  1 & + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8\\
                    & + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 3 + 5 + 6 ))
                  \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Nested `aligned` is more elegant, IMO, but here is another option using the `array` construct. Arrays are naturally more tight, so one can add `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}` to get lines a little spaced.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\noindent First with nested \verb|aligned|:
\begin{align*}
  A = ( 1 & + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 +10 + 11 + 12 \\
          &
            \begin{aligned}
              {} + 2 ( 1 & + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 \\
                      &
                        \begin{aligned}
                          {} + 3 ( 1 & + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 \\
                                  & + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4))
                        \end{aligned}
            \end{aligned} \\
          &
            \begin{aligned}
              {} + 2 ( 1 & + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8\\
                      & + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 3 + 5 + 6 ))
            \end{aligned}
\end{align*}
%
And with \verb|array|:
%
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{rlll}
  A = ( 1 & \multicolumn{3}{l}{{}+ 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 +10 + 11 + 12} \\
          & {} + 2 ( 1 & \multicolumn{2}{l}{{}+ 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10}\\
          &            & {} + 3 ( 1 & {}+ 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 \\
          &            &            & {}+ 1 + 2 + 3 + 4))\\
          & {} + 2 ( 1 & \multicolumn{2}{l}{{}+ 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8}\\
          &            & \multicolumn{2}{l}{{}+ 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 3 + 5 + 6 ))}\\
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

> [image]